Encrypting AES-GCM Key with AES or RSA?
I am building an application with a hierarchy of key-sets (think encrypted messaging). Each key-set contains:

Symmetric (AES-GCM-256)
Asymmetric (RSA-OASEP-256)

Each key-set defines an encrypted "store" where the symmetric key is used to encrypt json blobs "in" the store and the public key is used to encrypt items "contributed" to the store (in a pending state).
Within the key-set, the symmetric key is used to encrypt the private key of the key-pair.
Every store has a parent key-set, with the same symm/asymm key parameters, which is responsible for encrypting the store key-set.
Question:
Is there a security flaw (or draw back) if I encrypt the store symmetric key (AES-GCM-256) with the parent symmetric key (AES-GCM-256)?
Said differently:
Why should I not encrypt an AES-GCM-256 key with an other AES-GCM-256 key?
This encryption/decryption will be happening on the end-users devices (eg. mobile phones), so my preference would be to use AES-GCM for its efficiency over RSA-OAEP. However, this is all pointless if that introduces a security flaw.
Note: I did a little searching to see if there was a related answer and didn't seem to find anything. Either I was not asking the question correctly or didn't know the answer was staring at me. (So feel free to close a dup)


Is there a security flaw (or draw back) if I encrypt the store symmetric key (AES-GCM-256) with the parent symmetric key (AES-GCM-256)?

First of all, there is no such thing as an AES-GCM-256 key. There are 256 bit AES keys, but those are not specific to the mode of operation, in this case GCM. Same goes for RSA: you can use the key pairs for any kind of RSA operation, especially those defined in PKCS#1 (RSA-PKCS#1 v1.5, PSS or OAEP schemes).
Encrypting another key with a "parent" key is called key wrapping. The fact that it has been assigned a specific name already shows that this is a common operation required in many key management schemes. In e.g. PKCS#11 (Cryptoki) for e.g. HSM's and smart cards there are specific attributes such as CKA_WRAP and CKA_UNWRAP that indicate if the key can be used for key wrapping or not. Similarly, the X.509 key usage extension may be used to indicate keyEncipherment.
Some libraries even have a similar initialization or separate key wrap / unwrapping part in the library. This is useful if the unwrapped key needs to be placed in a key store. For instance in a HSM, if CK_UNWRAP is used then the resulting key will be stored into the HSM instead of exported out of the HSM.
Finally: quite often AES is used in SIV or GCM-SIV mode if key wrapping is required. This makes sure that no information about the key is leaked even if the local random number generator provides an insecure nonce, required by GCM. Randomly generated AES keys should be unique, so as long as this can be assured then the resulting ciphertext and tag will also be randomized.
Disclaimer: this is only a direct answer to the question; it should not be considered an in-depth protocol review (which would be off topic here anyway).

I appreciate your pedanticness, it is helpful, thank you. And thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the browser does not provide GCM-SIV so I think I am stuck with GCM only. And I agree with you, I need an in depth protocol review. But I am an unfunded solo operation for now, so volunteers welcomed

And for anyone else who read "stuck with GCM only" and thought I was wrong, you are correct! The browser DOES support GCM-SIV, but instead of using encrypt you use the aptly named wrapKey
